# Migrating all Data Over From App Engine NDB Over to Django Models Postgres

Tags: postgresql, django-models, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm new to data migrations, so I'm just wondering what the best way would be to go about migrating all of the data from the Big Table (NDB) over to Django Models (Postgres).

On the one hand, I have plenty of 'tables' that have plenty of relations (KeyProperties) and on the other, I must maintain those relations as well as port some over to general relations (GFK).

I'm not even sure how to go about doing this. I know how to create a Postgres Django DB, just not how to maintain things like, KeyProperties linking to image Blogs. How do I copy those images over and also maintain this 'FK' relation? I have quite a bit of data and would really like to maintain the structure of it.

Is there any good documents on database migrations and how its ideally done?

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

Create a Postgres table just for the images (using BLOB or `bytea` types) and use FK relations to it.

The general question of doing database migrations is too broad to answer, please ask a more specific question.  You are going to have to write custom code to split apart each entity's properties and convert them into Postgres data types.